# Github repos with CVEs mentioned and no real content

Tags: malware, cve

When I look for proof-of-concepts of a security vulnerability, I often see this kind of Github repositories:

> https://github.com/Satheesh575555/linux-4.19.72_CVE-2023-0386
>
> https://github.com/nidhi7598/linux-4.19.72_CVE-2022-29581

You could see that there is a pattern here in the name. Also, in the list of commits, there is almost nothing. At first I thought they had malware or something that would run when we tried to use them. But no, I diffed the content of these repos and the official linux 4.19.72, and they were almost identical. There were some minor differences, but they can't be malicious:

```
Only in linux-4.19.72_CVE-2023-0386: .whitesource

Files linux-4.19.72_CVE-2023-0386/fs/overlayfs/copy_up.c and official_linux-4.19.72/fs/overlayfs/copy_up.c differ
780,783d779
<    if (!kuid_has_mapping(current_user_ns(), ctx.stat.uid) ||
<        !kgid_has_mapping(current_user_ns(), ctx.stat.gid))
<        return -EOVERFLOW;
```

These two repos are just examples, and there are many other similar ones. Does anyone know why people created such repos? Some malicious intent here that I haven't figured out?

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not track PoC or exploit, quite to the contrary they track the fixes on branches of the kernel.

For CVE-2023-0386:
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-0386
...we can see among the references the fix from Torvalds:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=4f11ada10d0a
And the fix is precisely what your example is, except that it is for the 4.17 branch, whereas Torvalds fix was for v6.2-rc6.

So this *is* actual content. As of today there are 6 kernel branches (4.14, 4.19, 5.4, 5.10, 5.15, 6.1), and tracking the backport of a CVE that would be:

- discovered and fix on, say, 6.1,
- ...but for a bug that would have been introduced in 4.9 branch, not maintained anymore,
- ...but such a case would imply that the CVE should be fixed on all current 6 branches: where and how? The more different the branch, to more different the patch can be.

Such job is not only useful, it is *needed*. And not so easy to do, give it a try if you wish. ;-)

Comment: As I already said in the question, I know that the content in the repos can't be malicious. But my question is about why such repos exist. Even though they have actual content as you said, I don't see that they have any useful purpose. You could see that there is a pattern here in the names and the contents of the repos. There are many other similar ones that I didn't mention. It looks like the owners just want these repos to be showed when people search for the related CVEs.

Comment: If you don't understand the purpose, then you never had to sort out 500-1000 CVE yelds from the NVD on your kernel branch and version (with, of course, up to 95% false positives depending on your build configuration). Some people have been getting donations for such a service for years, e.g. https://www.linuxkernelcves.com/ from open data but closed source https://github.com/nluedtke/linux_kernel_cves.